# Как устранить ошибку воспроизведения аудио?

Tags: javascript, html

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

Что за ошибка и как устранить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use

Comment: **Почитайте справку**: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Jora Sahakyan, если вас мой ответ удовлетворил, то поставьте галочку рядом с ответом слева, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас обозреватель сети на основе Chrome, то вбейте в адресной строке:

> `chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy`

Там справа выберите: *No user gesture is required* (От пользователя действия не требуются)

Запустите Chrome повторно.

Если же у вас другой обозреватель сети, то измените соответствующую настройку для него.

Ничего в коде менять не нужно.

Это связано с самопроизвольным запуском (`autoplay`) и разрешением пользователя на него в настройках обозревателя сети.